# How to group JavaScript Object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, group

seek for help for grouping them. I got an input with this.

```js
[
    {
        "apiName": "APISend",
        "channel": "Mozilla",
        "noa": 3
    },
    {
        "apiName": "API",
        "channel": "PostMan",
        "noa": 1
    },
    {
        "apiName": "APICall",
        "channel": "PostMan",
        "noa": 4
    },
    {
        "apiName": "API",
        "channel": "Mozilla",
        "noa": 2
    }
]
```

How can I group them as channel and then by apiName? My final output should be like this:

```js
labels = ["Mozilla","PostMan"]

datasets = [{label:"APISend", data:[3,0]} , {label:"API",data:[2,1], {label:"APICall",data:[0,4]]}
```

Comment: What is `data` in `datasets` item?

Comment: Data is comes from noa. And it maps with labels. Let's say {label:"APISend", data:[3,0]}, the 3 is for Mozzila and 0 is for PostMan.

Comment: Can your input has these items `[ { "apiName": "APISend", "channel": "Mozilla", "noa": 3 },  { "apiName": "APISend", "channel": "Mozilla", "noa": 5 }]`?

Comment: No, I dont think so haha

Comment: Can you change the `data` format? I think it would better if `data` looks like this `data: {channel1: noaList, channel2: noaList, ....}`, where noaList is just array of `noa`s number. Because I think that in your input can be an item with `noa = 0` then you will not able to differ `0` for `noa` number and `0` for channel absence

Comment: Happy to help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just like this, you can have a try.

```
const arr = [{'apiName': 'APISend', 'channel': 'Mozilla', 'noa': 3}, {'apiName': 'API', 'channel': 'PostMan', 'noa': 1}, {'apiName': 'APICall', 'channel': 'PostMan', 'noa': 4}, {'apiName': 'API', 'channel': 'Mozilla', 'noa': 2}]

function transtArr(data){
  let labels = []
  let datasets = []
  data.forEach((value) => {
    labels.push(value.channel)
    let _indexNum = datasets.findIndex(x => x.label === value.apiName)
    if(_indexNum > -1){
      datasets[_indexNum].data.push(value.noa)
    } else {
      let _obj = {label: value.apiName, data: [value.noa]}
      datasets.push(_obj)
    }
  })
  return {labels: [...new Set(labels)], datasets}
}
```